# Spring data autowiring without webserver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, autowired

I just started using Spring Boot and love the simplicity of writing applications with it. I would like to know if and how it can be used to write (non web based) services with it.

I have a repository interface:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends MongoRepository<Order, String>
{

}
```

If I use @Autowired in a Spring boot application I can use it to do CRUD operations on my database.

However I would now like to use it in a simple application/test without all the webserver backend stuff.

However if I define the following test the repository interface has nothing to get autowired to:

```
public class TestMongoInterface
{
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    @Test
    public void canReadOrders()
    {
        List<Order> orders = orderRepository.findAll();
        for(Order o : orders)
            System.out.println("found: "+o.toString());
    }
}
```

I have found some workarounds which get close, but I if at all possible I would like to share my Repository interfaces between different services which these workarounds prevent.

So my question is: Is there a way to autowire the MongoRepository interface to my application where all the db query code gets generated but not all the other stuff I don't need like the webserver/servlet code?

Comment: and why wouldn't that work? Spring Boot != web... Just don't include the web dependency... It will work regardless of that. Testing spring boot application is quite clearly documented in it's reference guide.

Comment: Did you try [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)?

Comment: The problem is too much documentation and not knowing where to start, but apparently I was wrong to assume that Spring boot == web. So in stead of stripping I should find how to not add these components. I missed the -web in the spring-boot-starter-web dependency I will probably just have to find the appropriate dependency

Comment: If you dig a little deeper I can also encourage you to write an own starter with autoconfiguration instead of a common module. For us this is working like a charm to share common functionality.

Comment: See for example the guide [Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) for a simple, non-web Spring Boot application that uses a database and JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this its working fine when i use JpaRepository. Without autowiring its not possible.

```
 @Configuration
    public class TestMongoInterface
    {
        @Autowired
        private OrderRepository orderRepository;
        @Autowired
        public void canReadOrders()
        {
            List<Order> orders = orderRepository.findAll();
            for(Order o : orders)
                System.out.println("found: "+o.toString());
        }
    }
```